# Is "atashita" short for "atashitachi"?

Tags: words, slang

In an anime episode, I heard a sentence I didn't quite understand. I don't have the japanese subtitles to be sure, but what I heard is:

> 勝負{しょうぶ}してんだろう、あたした！

The meaning I understand is something like "*It's competitive between you and me, don't you agree?*", and it's what the subtitles seem to means (the wording is *very* different), but that would mean あたした is short for 私達, is that the case?

I know about あたし for 私, the speaker is a woman so it makes sense, but I've never seen た for 達 before and I can't make sense of the sentence if it doesn't mean "*you and I*".

---

It's from *Tomo-chan is a girl*, Ep. 10, around 3:03.

Comment: I checked the video, and she's just saying あたしと, "(You're competing) with me". I'm voting to close this as a "typo" question. たち never contracts to た.

Comment: I checked the video too. She says 勝負して**え**んだろ、あたしと！

Comment: @naruto Fair enough! Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

[Cursory answer since I can't check the episode right now]

No, たち to just た as far as I'm aware. It's more likely she said 「勝負してんだろ、あたしたぁ！」 where 「たぁ」 is a slurring of とは. It's a little 'crude' but the speaker seems to talk crudely in general.

The sentence is also reversed so in full 「あたしとは勝負しているだろう！」

So basically, the sentence as presented is 'You're having a match with me, ain'tcha?!'

EDIT: I have checked the episode now. She says 「勝負**してえんだろ**、あたしたぁ！」, where してえ is a crude colloquial pronunciation of したい 'want to do'. 'You wannna compete with me, don'tcha?!' is how I'd translate it in light of that. From your transcription I had assumed this to be 「してんだろ」 that's a contraction of 「している（の）だろう」 but that was wrong.